# How to change tab bar item size in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below `TabBar`:

```
bottom: TabBar(
                  onTap: (index) {
                    cubit.changeBottomNavIndex(index);
                  },
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: goldDefaultColor, width: 1),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    color: Colors.grey[600],
                  ),
                  labelColor: goldDefaultColor,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                  tabs: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Live',
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 5.0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Map',
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Device',
                    ),
                  ],
                  controller: _tabController,
                ),
```

looks like the below image:

[image]

I want to make it smaller like the below image:
[image]

is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the size of tabs to be the minimum size by adding

```
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
```

to TabBar widget